# How to simulate a Real Mouse click for DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a web application which is on HTML5... In that i have a dojo dialogue box for some user operations... Now i want to click the title bar of that dialogue box... The title bar of the dialogue box is accessible by `ele = document.getElementById("searchFrame_title");`...

and i am performing the click on the dialogue box's title bar by this...

```
ele = document.getElementById("searchFrame_title");
ele.style.cursor = 'move';
var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    view : window,
    bubbles : true,
    cancelable : true,
    }), ele = document.getElementById("searchFrame_title");
ele.dispatchEvent(evt);
alert("clicked");
```

While everything's fine but on clicking the title bar of the dojo dialogue box it doesn't comes in visible area...

**Scenario...**

I dragged the dialogue box at the bottom of the web page(really bottom any further will push it upwards). then i performed a click on the box which appends some data on the dialogue box due to which the data appended goes inside the screen.

**Problem...**

When i click on the title bar manually the dialogue box automatically moves it upwards to the viewable area calculated from the bottom. But when i simulate the click from the code(shown above), it doesn't do so...

How to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning is not done at the click time but at the end drag time. Simulating a click does not trigger the drag mechanism.

However, you can workaround it.  That's a dirty trick but you can call `_endDrag()` method of the dialog (instead of simulating a click) 
See:

```js
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
    var dialog = new Dialog({
          content: document.getElementById('dialogContent')
    });
    dialog.show();
  
   document.getElementById('repositionMe').onclick = function() {
     dialog._endDrag();
   }
   document.getElementById('addTo').onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<br>' + document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<body class = "tundra">
  
<div id="dialogContent">
    <button id="addTo">add content</button>
  <button id="repositionMe">reposition me</button>
  <div id="content">this is the content of the dialog</div>

</div>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: It would be somewhat less hacky (and still works, AFAICT) to call `dialog._position()` instead of `_endDrag`.  `_position` is the important part of what `_endDrag` actually does here.

Comment: I tested that but it wasn't working. Even `resize()` should be enough but somehow it is not...

Comment: Hm, weird.  Yeah, `resize` hadn't worked for me either, but looking at Dialog's code I'm not immediately sure why not.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer... Your code solved it... I just needed the _endDrag() method.